# Binary mask in Tensorflow

Tags: arrays, tensorflow, masking

I would like to mask every other value along a particular dimension of a Tensor but don't see a good way to generate such a mask. For example

```
#Masking on the 2nd dimension
a = [[1,2,3,4,5],[6,7,8,9,0]
mask = [[1,0,1,0,1],[1,1,1,1,1]]
b = a * mask #would return [[1,0,3,0,5],[6,0,8,0,0]]
```

Is there an easy way to generate such a mask?

Ideally I would like to do something like the following:

```
mask = tf.ones_like(input_tensor)
mask[:,::2] = 0
mask * input_tensor
```

But slice assigning doesn't seem to be as simple as in Numpy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily programmatically create such a tensor mask using python.  Then convert it to a tensor.  There's no such support in the TensorFlow API.  [tf.tile([1,0], num_of_repeats)](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.11/api_docs/python/array_ops.html#tile) might be a fast way to create such mask but not that great either if you have odd number of columns.

(Btw, if you end up creating a boolean mask, use [tf.boolean_mask()](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.11/api_docs/python/array_ops.html#boolean_mask))

Comment: I can guaruntee in my case that the dimension I want to mask has an even number of elements so this works perfectly. Thanks!

Comment: I don't think tf.boolean_mask() preserves the dimensions of the original tensor. It rather returns the non-masked elements in 1-d shape.

Answer (score 4):

Currently, Tensorflow [does not support](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/206) numpy-like assignment.

Here is a couple of workarounds:

## tf.Variable

`tf.Tensor` cannot be changed, but `tf.Variable` can.

```
a = tf.constant([[1,2,3,4,5],[6,7,8,9,10]])

mask = tf.Variable(tf.ones_like(a, dtype=tf.int32))
mask = mask[0,1::2]
mask = tf.assign(mask, tf.zeros_like(mask))
# mask = [[1,0,1,0,1],[1,1,1,1,1]]

tf.InteractiveSession()
tf.global_variables_initializer().run()
print(mask.eval())
```

## tf.sparse_to_dense()

```
indices = tf.range(1, 5, 2)
indices = tf.stack([tf.zeros_like(indices), indices], axis=1)
# indices = [[0,1],[0,3]]
mask = tf.sparse_to_dense(indices, a.shape, sparse_values=0, default_value=1)
# mask = [[1,0,1,0,1],[1,1,1,1,1]]

tf.InteractiveSession()
print(mask.eval())
```

Comment: Actually, this doesn't answer the OPs question. They asked how do you *generate* such a mask programmatically?

Comment: @Multihunter, fixed.

Comment: Note that for the tf.variable solution, you probably want to set trainable=False

Answer (score 2):

There's a more efficient solution, but this will certainly get the job done

```
myshape = myTensor.shape
# create tensors of your tensor's indices:
row_idx, col_idx = tf.meshgrid(tf.range(myshape[0]), tf.range(myshape[1]), indexing='ij')
# create boolean mask of odd numbered columns on a particular row.
mask = tf.where((row_idx == N) * (col_idx % 2 == 0), False, True)

masked = tf.boolean_mask(myTensor, mask)
```

in general you can adapt this method for any such index-based masks, and to rank-n tensors